# Viabilidad de puntuar negativamente a usuarios nuevos

Tags: discusión

Buen día comunidad de Meta SOes.

He observado durante varias semanas muchos usuarios nuevos a los cuales se les ha puntuado negativamente sus preguntas sin explicarles el por qué. Siendo usuarios nuevos creo que sería propicio intentar orientarles en que están haciendo mal. A continuación muestro algunos ejemplos de apenas las primeras 5 páginas de SOes:

[image: Usuario nuevo 1 puntuado negativamente]

> **Descripción:** La imagen anterior muestra a un usuario prácticamente nuevo realizando una pregunta que no creo que esté del todo mal porque
>   incluso coloca un enlace y la descripción (en mi opinión) es bastante
>   clara. Aún así ha sido puntuado negativamente sin explicación. Yo no
>   me imagino cual es el motivo de los negativos así que dudo que el OP
>   de esta pregunta siendo usuario nuevo lo sepa.

[image: Usuario nuevo 2 puntuado negativamente]

> **Descripción**: La imagen anterior muestra a un usuario totalmente nuevo cuyo título de su pregunta es bastante claro y suministra código
>   en su descripción. En el código se nota claramente lo que intenta
>   lograr. En este caso creo que un parrafo explicativo en la descripción
>   de la pregunta aparte del código es necesaria y puede que por
>   eso sean los negativos. Notemos que sólo podemos "imaginar" por qué
>   fue puntuado negativamente entonces como el OP se entera de su error?

[image: Usuario nuevo 3 puntuado negativamente]

> **Descripción:** Otro usuario totalmente nuevo que había sido puntuado negativamente (tenía -1 pero yo lo puntué positivamente y quedó en
>   cero). Lo que hago en la mayoría de los casos como este es pedir en un
>   comentario que por favor expliquen al usuario nuevo que esta mal en su
>   pregunta para que la pueda corregir. Acto seguido a ello le dejo mi
>   impresión de por qué puede que esté mal su pregunta y que puede hacer
>   para mejorarla/corregirla.

[image: Usuario nuevo 4 puntuado negativamente]

> **Descripción:** Parecido a los casos anteriores en la imagen se muestra
>   otra vez como se puntua negativamente al usuario nuevo sin explicación
>   alguna.

Mi duda es: Para que existen los reportes en las preguntas? No es justamente para que se atienda oportunamente lo que se considera que esta mal y se encamine para que esté bien?

Parece que los usuarios "experimentados" se dan la tarea de puntuar negativamente a un usuario nuevo y consideran innecesario explicar el por qué. Evidentemente no es una obligación explicarlo pero sí una consideración importante a tomar en cuenta cuando los usuarios que preguntan son nuevos.

> Si el interés es desechar una pregunta que no ha sido formulada
>   correctamente o de alguna forma intentar "salvarla" por medio de una edición 
>   no sería mejor (obviando el negativo) reportar la pregunta?

De esta forma los moderadores se pueden percatar y atendiendo el caso explican por qué la pregunta no fue bien recibida y que se debe hacer para corregirla. Por lo visto es la única forma que el usuario nuevo tiene para conocer que hizo mal y corregirlo

Si tratamos tan duramente a aquellos que recien empiezan su trayecto por este sitio dificilmente se queden por mucho tiempo en la comunidad. Al final lo más importante de una comunidad son sus usuarios y si hablamos de nuevos usuarios debemos valorarlos mucho ya que son aquellos que "oxigenan" el sitio, lo hacen más grande e importante de lo que ya es y en un futuro puede que sean parte de aquellos que lo mantienen activo y velan por su correcto funcionamiento.

Es mi humilde opinión y mi intención es que se mejore más el sitio (que me parece prácticamente perfecto ya). Espero podamos llegar a crear una característica nueva o al menos una alternativa para evitar que esto se propague ya que pienso que en cierta forma estamos "estimulando" a que usuarios nuevos de la comunidad no duren mucho tiempo en la misma.

Comment: Considera poner un **TL;DR** ;)

Comment: Me parece "muy aventurado", por llamarlo de alguna forma, el generalizar a partir de preguntas que tienen pocos votos y vistas, por otro lado, si bien es útil dejar una captura, más útil sería el dejar el enlace las preguntas en cuestión

Comment: Pro tip: Mira la cronología de las publicaciones usando urls con el patrón siguiente `/posts/[numero-de-pregunta]/timeline`

Comment: Ok @KacosPro TL;DR jaja xD!

Comment: Lo pensé al revés @Rubén creía que las capturas serían más descriptivas. Tiene razón he debido dejar los enlaces. En un momento coloco los enlaces. Es cierto, es "muy aventurado" quizás doy esa impresión porque escogí las últimas cuatro publicaciones de forma aleatoria. Conseguiré unas cuantas un poco mas viejas y con más vistas para añadirlas

Comment: @Rubén Muchas gracias por el pro tip. No conocía que se pudiese esto.

Comment: Lo de los enlaces queda como deuda. Han eliminado 3 de las preguntas y solo han quedado las siguientes: [Clase singleton](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171074/como-convertir-clase-a-singleton) y [función azure](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171076/leer-un-archivo-largo-en-una-función-duradera-de-azure)

Comment: He vistoeso mismo en muchas preguntas, y aunqu en algunos casos esta justificados los comentarios de que la pregunta no es apropiada según las normas de SOes, en muchos otros casos es simplemente el resultado de no tener ni idea sobre el tema sobre el que va la pregunta. De hecho en muchos casos incluso suele haber una respuesta muy apropiada y concreta, tanto como la pregunta cuando se sabe de que se habla realmente.

Comment: @JuanJoseBurgosVeiga Si, pasa muy seguido. Hay preguntas que son puntuadas negativamente y nunca se sabrá por què ha pasado esto. A mi me han puntuado negativamente aún cuando la pregunta cumple con las reglas y está bien redactada. Yo pienso que para dar negativo debería ser obligatorio asociar un comentario porque es la única forma que el OP tiene para notar si está algo malo con su pregunta. Pero bueno la mayoría acepta que siga funcionando como va y toca respetar eso

Comment: Yo votaría negativamente (y para cerrar) sin ninguna duda el tercer ejemplo. Mi visión de los otros usuarios es de gente con la que quizás un día acabe trabajando. Y francamente, me horroriza la idea de encontrarme con alguien que piense que su "trabajo" es poner la descripción del problema en SOe para que alguien se lo resuelva, que él no tiene que preocuparse en aprender de verdad a programar. No veo ningún problema en tratar de hacerles entender, sin aplicar paños calientes, en qué consiste el trabajo de programador; cuando antes lo entiendan mejor.

Comment: @SJuan76 Es así. Tienes razón, lo que pedía era un poco de paciencia para los usuarios nuevos ya que en muchos casos ves sus fotos de perfil y son niños que están aprendiendo a programar. Otros usuarios aclaran que están empezando en el mundo de la programación. Empiezan aquí y los funden a negativos sin explicación. Cuando yo empecé me paso; mi problema no era de redacción, formato, etc era más bien porque la pregunta era basada en opiniones.  me "fundieron" a negativos y tuve que solicitar la intervención de un moderador para entender que hacia mal.

Comment: @SJuan76 Aún así. estoy totalmente de acuerdo con tu opinión porque incentiva la excelencia en el sitio y en los usuarios. Gracias por tu aporte

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hay muchos puntos que tratar en tu pregunta, voy a intentar responder a todo (había empezado en los comentarios, pero me estaba quedando algo realmente largo, así que opto por ponerlo como respuesta para darle algo de mejor formato).

Debes tener en cuenta que no todos los usuarios tienen [privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) para reportar preguntas de este tipo (aunque se podrían reportar a los moderadores). Para votar se necesitan menos puntos (15 para votar positivo, 125 para votar negativo) que para revisar preguntas o pedir cierre/reapertura (500 y 3.000 respectivamente).

Aparte de eso, básicamente todas las preguntas que expones son de muy baja calidad y deberían estar en el proceso de ser cerradas si no lo han sido ya (y definitivamente no deberían haber obtenido puntos positivos porque no cumplen con los criterios mínimos de calidad esperados en una pregunta):

1. El [primer ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/171076/250) no es un usuario nuevo-nuevo (tiene pocos puntos pero lleva 2 años registrado y ha realizado 10 publicaciones); a la pregunta le falta información clave para poder ayudarle (el código, los errores) y el enlace es a un tutorial que está siguiendo, no a su código (puede haber copiado algo mal y eso crear el error).
2. [El segundo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/171074/250) sí es un usuario nuevo, pero la pregunta es de muy baja calidad: el cuerpo es sólo código y no queda claro si eso es el código que quiere convertir o su intento de conversión. Hace falta una mejor descripción del problema y de lo intentado, las preguntas sin un enunciado claro no son de ayuda a otros usuarios (ya sea porque tienen un problema similar o porque quiere ayudar a resolverlo).
3. [El tercer ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/171156/250) es una imagen sin más y pidiendo cómo podría hacerse. Aparte de ser una pregunta increíblemente amplia, se basa principalmente en opiniones (en parte por no ser concreta). Es de muy baja calidad y es normal que haya acabado eliminada (por el propio usuario). Pero ojo, antes de ser eliminada fue cerrada como demasiado amplia (se ve en la captura), y en el mensaje de cierre hay una razón para ese cierre y enlaces con la misma información que los moderadores u otros usuarios dejan en las publicaciones de este tipo.
4. El [cuarto ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/171032/250) no se ve completo, pero realmente no hay más de lo que se ve en la imagen: una gráfica y código, es muy pobre en detalles, sin una descripción del problema o de las dificultades/errores que se encuentra. Además de que le falta código importante para entender el problema (algo que un usuario le decía en la sección de comentarios). Tiene los mismos problemas que el segundo ejemplo. El propio usuario borró la pregunta y acabó [creando otra similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/171160/250) en la que sí obtuvo respuesta (a pesar de ser también de baja calidad y no incluir la información solicitada en la pregunta original).

Con eso no intento justificar los votos negativos a las preguntas, pero lanzar algo de luz sobre por qué los recibieron. Estoy totalmente de acuerdo contigo en que se debería tener más paciencia con los usuarios nuevos y guiarlos para que mantengan el entusiasmo y participación en el sitio.

...pero (casi siempre hay un pero), ser más paciente con los usuarios nuevos no significa un "todo vale" para ellos: si una pregunta no se ajusta a la temática o formato del sitio, debe dejarse un comentario o votar por cerrar, o los dos, y en ciertos casos, votar negativo.

Como criterio personal, no voto negativo en esos casos y suelo dejar un comentario (o voto por cerrar si es un caso claro que no se ajusta al formato/temática del sitio)... pero cada usuario puede elegir la opción que considere más acertada.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con tu respuesta. Yo personalmente no voto casi nunca negativo a los usuarios nuevos, o no sin al menos antes dejarles un comentario explicando que están haciendo mal, y en todo caso tras el comentario voto por cerrar si la pregunta está claramente fuera de la temática.

Comment: Si. Quizás no escogí los mejores ejemplos. Quiero aclarar que mi intención con la pregunta es tratar de alguna forma de incentivar a los usuarios que puntuan negativamente a los usuarios nuevos a explicarles en un sencillo comentario el por qué. Así el OP aprende de su error e intentará no cometerlo nuevamente (ya que imagino le interesa respondan a su pregunta). Es una forma de apoyar a los moderadores también porque aunque no soy moderador si pienso que debe ser tedioso estar explicando el por qué de los negativos de otros usuarios al OP

Comment: Tal cual como refiere @Pikoh y usted Sr Montoro tampoco voto negativo a usuarios nuevos. De hecho si veo una publicación puntuada negativamente de un OP nuevo intento explicarle el por qué su pregunta está siendo mal recibida por la comunidad e intento orientarle para que mejore el formato/redacción. Normalmente si la puedo salvar editandola la edito.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta. Ya me queda claro este punto también. Nada que hacer, seguiré intentando explicar a los usuarios nuevos que estén siendo puntuados negativamente sin comentarios como mejorar sus preguntas y por qué considero que los puntuaron negativamente así quizás evito el rato amargo a muchos de ellos. En su momento me pasó con una pregunta que hasta el día de hoy no sé que tenía de malo (era nuevo, obtuve -3 en una pregunta y nadie comentó, así que opté por borrarla antes de que la "fundieran" a negativos)

Comment: Creeme, estoy 100% contigo en esto. Lo que quieres hacer es muy noble y bueno para los usuarios nuevos que necesitan más orientación y paciencia. Lo malo es que te vas a encontrar remando en contra de otra corriente de Stack Overflow (lo cual no es malo en sí, aunque puede ser frustrante a veces)... pero creo que los resultados a largo plazo merecen la pena.

Comment: Si @AlvaroMontoro tienes razón! es que aún cuando lo propuesto representaría una mejora si la mayoría acostumbra a puntuar negativamente sin comentar pues nada que hacer

Answer (score 0):

Mi humilde opinion, la cual creo que no va a ser demasiado compartida pero aún así quiero dejar plasmada:

Juzgar la calidad de la pregunta en usuarios inexperimentados en el sitio y en base a ello calificar negativamente carece de sentido.

Por que?

a) Un usuario nuevo carece de conocimientos del sitio. Uds dirán, "pero para que esta el tour inicial entonces?" Quizá el usuario lo tomó y de todas formas generó una pregunta de baja calidad, no por poca disposición sino porque fué lo que llegó a elaborar. No hay que juzgar la capacidad de la persona que pregunta y calificarla negativamente, no es la idea del sitio en mi opinión. Aunque se lean las FAQs, el tour, etc, la experiencia no la tienen, y con ella se aprende a lograr preguntas de calidad.

b) Calificaciones negativas solo generan rechazo, lo único que se logra es que dicha persona se distancie mas de SOes. Nadie quiere eso.

Que alternativas veo?

- Calificaciones solo positivas para personas con reputación menor a 200 (este valor es arbitrario)
- Denunciar preguntas por baja calidad para esos usuarios
- Detectar cuando uno de esos usuarios repite un numero X (3 por ejemplo) de preguntas de baja calidad y en ese momento si habilitar calificaciones negativas.

Me parece mas justo, no se si es viable en la plataforma de SOes implementar este mecanismo, pero las "advertencias" evitarían el alejamiento de esos usuarios y a su vez también evitarían un mayor trabajo de el resto de los usuarios y moderadores.

Probablemente hayan muchos usuarios respetados o que hayan realizado aportes muy útiles en la comunidad que sintieron cierta "hostilidad" en su primer posteo y simplemente aprendieron luego. No quita que estos usuarios quizá ni siquiera se tomaron la molestia de leer el tour, pero en mi opinión pesa mucho más generar una base de conocimiento mayor, de más calidad, captar personas con algo para aportar a simplemente "castigar" con votos negativos para hacer valer al 100% las reglas.

Se pierde mas de lo que se gana, si se logra espantar a alguien que pudo en algún momento elaborar una buena respuesta por el mero hecho de que no pudo tolerar un primer posteo con calificación de -5 estamos perdiendo.

Comment: Estaría de acuerdo contigo si no hubiera visto justo hoy dos preguntas que eran un _copy paste_ de su examen. ¿Que recomendarías en esos casos?

Comment: Prueba 1: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/173736/hola-programadores-alguien-me-puede-ayudar-a-resolver-este-proyecto-es-en-psein

Comment: Prueba 2: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/173771/hola-necesito-crear-un-algoritmo-en-pseint-juego-de-pelea-por-turnos

Comment: Creo que se podría aplicar el criterio general de lo que propongo, se trata de personas que recibirían una denuncia, se les sugeriría leer el tour y quedarían con el primer strike. Serían preguntas que, en el caso de que el usuario no decida mejorar su elaboración, quedarían con reputación 0 en lugar de -3. No veo sinceramente que puede ser lo malo de ello.

Comment: Es decir, si vamos a los números, se traduciría en mayor cantidad de preguntas con 0 de reputación en lugar de negativas para personas con reputación baja (usuarios inexperimentados). No veo como pueda afectar negativamente al sitio y si encuentro algo positivo en no generar rechazo en esas personas nuevas.

Comment: Quizá me expresé mal, me refería a los votos de las preguntas no la reputación del usuario.

Comment: Para un nuevo usuario no es lo mismo enfrentarse a sugerencias de como mejorar su pregunta si la misma se mantiene con 0 votos a si 3 personas la calificaron negativamente. Para mi en usuarios nuevos ni como ultimo recurso tiene sentido, no comparto en ese aspecto ya que para ese usuario, el cual no conoce como funciona el sitio lo ve como "injustificado" o "hostil". Y basicamente no se logra nada, preguntas con 1 año de antiguedad con -5 de calificación donde el usuario no le interesaba mas nada.. sería lo mismo si las dejamos con 0 y captamos a los usuarios que si las cambiarian

Comment: Retiro mi comentario anterior pero me mantengo en su punto, la primera pregunta está llena de comentarios **ignorados por el autor** con sugerencias de como mejorarla. No sirvió de nada comentar en una pregunta de un usuario que no le interesa aprender, si no que, solo quiere que le den el código para resolver su problema sin haber intentando nada antes, por lo tanto si no hacen caso a los comentarios tal vez sí lo hagan a los votos, por consecuencia eliminarán una mala pregunta del sitio y crearán una nueva de mejor calidad.

Comment: Vale la pena comentar para enseñar a los usuarios a utilizar el sitio, los que hacen caso a las recomendaciones son los que merecen el esfuerzo, para los que no les interesa están los votos.

Comment: Insisto en que, en el caso de tu ejemplo, da igual dejarlo con 0 que con -10. Por que? Porque en los hechos queda una pregunta sin responder e ignorada por el usuario que la realizó. Que ganamos con dejarla en 0? Que personas que realmente no hayan entendido las reglas y tengan ganas de aprenderlas no se vean rechazadas porque (personas diferentes a ti, que utilizan el voto negativo NO como ultimo recurso) las califiquen negativamente. Es decir, es mas lo que se gana que lo que se pierde.

Comment: Y yo estoy totalmente de acuerdo contigo en que, lo que necesita el sitio son usuarios nuevos, por lo que primero descarto todos los recursos a mi alcance antes de utilizar el -1, como tu bien dices _es más lo que se gana que lo que se pierde_. Pero insisto en mi punto y hay un vacío ahí ¿qué se podría hacer con los usuarios a los que no les interesa leer nada más que la respuesta a su solución si haber hecho un esfuerzo previo? Para estos los votos son lo único que queda

Comment: Entiendo tu punto y es una buena pregunta la que haces y justamente es a lo que apunto, mi respuesta sería "Nada", simplemente no haría nada con esos usuarios. No se logra absolutamente nada con votos negativos con usuarios de esa caracteristicas, puesto que como tu dices, no les interesa leer nada y no lo harán (a menos que arguementes que los votos negativos generan un impacto positivo en esos usuarios, lo cual puede ser valido). Ahora, si justo estamos ante un usuario que no es de esas caracteristicas le estamos dando 3 oportunidades antes de ser "penalizados" con votos.

Comment: No comprendo porque tiene que haber 3 "oportunidades". Que a la primera se le diga "esto no funciona así, lee el tour y ayuda y mira las otras preguntas", de acuerdo. Pero si decide ignorar ese consejo, ¿no es su responsabilidad? Y completamente en desacuerdo también en impedir votar negativamente a usuarios con menos de 200 puntos, la política del sitio es **"Se vota a la pregunta, no al usuario"**.

Comment: Y por supuesto, recordar que un voto negativo o de cierre no tiene más valor allá de la pregunta; no es que se le vaya a poner una multa a un usuario o siquiera limitar su capacidad para escribir preguntas o respuestas. En el caso de usuarios nuevos, ni siquiera restará cuando obtenga votos positivos. No veo la necesidad de ser tan precavidos con una herramienta de efectos tan limitados. Si alguien no es capaz de soportar una crítica (siempre, por supuesto, respetando la necesidad de un trato educado), es muy difícil que mejore, tanto en programación como en cualquier otro aspecto.

Comment: Lo importante en mi opinión es que al menos se le comente al usuario porque lo "funden" a negativos de esta forma él entiende que está haciendo algo mal y queda a su conciencia si lo corrige o no. Si no lo corrige pues no le tocará otra que irse del sitio porque aquí hay reglas y si las corrige bienvenido sea sus aportes valiosos a esta comunidad. Justo captaste la esencia de lo que intenté explicar. Gracias por tu valioso aporte @MarcosMartínez

Comment: Cómo saben que somos perfeccionistas? cómo saben que buscamos la excelencia? cómo saben que en este sitio existen las reglas? Pensemos en un caso práctico, cuando tu compras un celular nuevo me vas a decir que lees el manual? Para nada (en la gran mayoría de los casos) empiezas a experimentar o a "jugar" con el móvil para ver que hace y que no. Luego puede que leas el manual ante alguna duda. Lo mismo pasa con los usuarios nuevos, leen las reglas al llegar? no, esta bien eso? tampoco pero esta peor que los usuarios que puntuen negativo no hagan saber del error al op

Comment: Estoy totalmente de acuerdo con tu respuesta. Siento que como comunidad a los usuarios nuevos les generamos una muy mala impresión y concluyo que, en cierta forma, muchos se van de aquí pensando que somos tóxicos y no perfeccionistas o fieles seguidores de las reglas del sitio. Por qué? Pues porque nunca le explicamos a los usuarios nuevos cuáles son sus errores. Ya a mí me paso esto cuando fuí nuevo y no me gusto para nada. Me resultó incómodo solicitar a un moderador para que me explicará el -3 que tenía en mi primera pregunta "sin razón" porque nadie explicaba

Comment: Para concluir, es mi culpa que esta pregunta no rinda más frutos por haber escogido los peores ejemplos para mostrar. Pero pasa como siempre, esta semana cantidad de usuarios nuevos y cantidad de preguntas puntuadas negativamente sin explicación alguno, el usuario nuevo perdido, de hecho, dos de ellos preguntaron en su propia pregunta: por qué el negativo?

Comment: "Calificaciones solo positivas para personas con reputación menor a 200"....no puedo estar más en desacuerdo con esta idea, realmente es abrir las puertas a preguntas de mala calidad, spam y ruido indeseado en el sitio