# ¿Deberíamos permitir preguntas que buscan respuestas tipo wiki?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, wiki-de-comunidad

Durante estos meses en SOes, he notado varias preguntas (la mayoría de usuarios nuevos) que para otros usuarios podrían parecer básicas y reciben entonces:

- **Votos negativos**. En este punto estoy en desacuerdo hacerlo con los usuarios nuevos, este es un tema que ya se ha tratado ampliamente [aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3519/viabilidad-de-puntuar-negativamente-a-usuarios-nuevos) y también [por aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/616/83304).
- **Cerradas**: Como demasiado amplias o basadas en opiniones.
- **Comentarios hostiles** tipo *"Hay mil resultados en Google, busca ahí..."*
- Links de la misma pregunta con una posible respuesta, pero de SO en inglés.

Este último punto [es debatible](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/14/son-aceptables-las-traducciones-directas-de-respuestas-de-stackoverflow-en-ingl), yo pienso que no se debería enlazar el link a SOen como comentario, sino tratar en lo posible de traducirlo y publicarlo como respuesta, dando crédito al creador original.

Pero la mayoría de estas preguntas, aunque amplias, aunque sencillas de explicar para muchos (y por ende no se esfuerzan en contestar); son preguntas interesantes en el contexto de que a futuro pueden ser consultadas por muchos usuarios y dan a conecer mucho mejor SO en español.

Pongo como ejemplo esta pregunta (que ya lleva 2 votos negativos):

[¿Existen diferencias entre SCSS y CSS?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270896/existen-diferencias-entre-scss-y-css)

Muchos podrían opinar: *"Es una pregunta basada en opiniones o es muy amplia"*, no se esmeran en dar una respuesta, sino que simplemente acuden a un escueto [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270896/existen-diferencias-entre-scss-y-css#comment499001_270896) o peor, acuden a cualquiera de los puntos arriba mencionados.

Otros podrían pensar: *"Esta pregunta tan simple, de seguro ya se hizo en el sitio y debe ser un duplicado"*. Pero para sorpresa, esta pregunta se encuentra en el sitio en inglés con unas **valoraciones muy altas**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654447/whats-the-difference-between-scss-and-sass

Al punto que quiero llegar es, ¿porqué no nos esforzamos en crear respuestas canónicas para estas preguntas "simples" pero interesantes, en vez de acudir a un ataque de votos negativos?

¿Deberíamos y podríamos ser más flexibles con este tipo de preguntas? Creo que ya lo hemos sido con otras preguntas en el pasado, por ejemplo, con [las preguntas top en el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes), la gran mayoría hoy podrían considerarse demasiado amplias o basadas en opiniones, pero no por eso dejan de ser muy útiles y de gran beneficio para la comunidad.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94810/discussion-on-question-by-jheyman-mejia-deberiamos-permitir-preguntas-que-busca).

Comment: respecto a "no se debería enlazar el link a SOen como comentario, sino tratar en lo posible de traducirlo y publicarlo como respuesta, dando crédito al creador original" si no tengo tiempo enlazo a una respuesta, que otro la traduzca es parte del trabajo colaborativo.

Comment: @gbianchi ¿Era necesario mover los comentarios a un chat?, es la primera vez que veo que se haga ello en un sitio meta, nunca ví ese tipo de acciones en https://meta.stackexchange.com . Y eso no se hace para que los futuros lectores vean rapidamente los comentarios

Comment: Era un lio de comentarios muy largos. Me parecio algo mas comodo, sobre todo porque era una discusion mas que todo entre ustedes.. si te parece que cometi un error te pido disculpas... @eyllanesc

Comment: @gbianchi yo pienso que justamente META esta para discusiones cortas o largas entre un par de personas o entre todos. Si piensas que es un discusión larga que no ayuda a la comunidad pudiste informarnos y decirnos tu punto de vista respecto a ello. En SO si es válido moverlo a un chat porque alli no es un sitio de discusiones pero aqui sí, pienso que no deberias hacerlo, no es necesario las disculpas entiendo tu punto de vista que son adecuados para SO pero no para meta

Comment: Ok. Entiendo tu punto y acepto mi error en no pedirles que lo siguieran en un chat. @eyllanesc