# No entiendo el cierre de ciertas preguntas

Tags: discusión, preguntas, cierre-de-preguntas

[¿Por qué los tipos de datos primitivos tienen un tamaño fijo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/547797/por-qu%c3%a9-los-tipos-de-datos-primitivos-tienen-un-tama%c3%b1o-fijo)

Pues lo dicho, no entiendo los motivos para cerrar esta pregunta. No es el primer caso que me encuentro, pero no me voy a poner a rebuscar las otras preguntas cerradas que me han motivado a abrir este hilo.

El caso es ¿Qué más detalles hacen falta para que la pregunta sea aceptada?

La pregunta es clara y concisa. ¿Por qué los tipos primitivos tienen un tamaño fijo?

¿Qué esperamos entonces? ¿Que nos ponga un código de ejemplo en el que se vea que un `int` ocupa 4 bytes ? ¿?

Creo que en ocasiones somos demasiado estrictos a la hora de votar cierres, y cierres como este dificultan que el portal despegue y tenga más presencia.

Al fin y al cabo este tipo de situaciones acaban dando la impresión, desde mi punto de vista, que para que te respondan a ciertas preguntas debes irte a la versión inglesa y pasar de la versión de habla hispana.

¿Qué pensais al respecto?

Comment: Opino exactamente lo mismo.. Es mas, la primera vez que vi la pregunta, dije que se parecia mas a basada en opiniones, pero ni siquiera vote (ademas de porque la cerraba automaticamente) si no porque en mi cabeza, esas opiniones se arreglaban con dos toques por ahi... No entendi el cierre de que faltan detalles.. estoy con vos en que no se que detalles faltan... Ni siquiera le dejaron un comentario de que detalles agregar...

Comment: En el caso particular de la pregunta enlazada, realmente parece una pregunta interesante, además no se responde necesariamente con "hay que preguntarle al autor del lenguaje". Eso sí, fue peor recibida en [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66079316/why-do-primitive-data-types-have-a-fixed-size) y [SO en Portugués](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/559752/por-que-os-tipos-de-dados-primitivos-s%c3%a3o-fixos-em-tamanho).

Comment: @padaleiana hay gente que debe ser la leche de lista y debe pensar que hay una serie de conocimientos que la gente debe nacer con ellos o si no debería simplemente desaparecer. En el fondo StackOverflow no deja de ser un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. Mientras el tema tenga sentido dentro del sitio y haya, efectivamente, una pregunta de alcance razonable, no veo motivos para cerrarla ... otra cosa es que la respuesta se pueda encontrar de forma sencilla o trivial con una simple búsqueda en Internet ... y que por eso se gane algún negativo... pero tampoco creo que sea el caso

Comment: @padaleiana por cierto, la pregunta tenía un -4 en el momento de abrir este hilo. Ha recibido 4 positivos y eso ha equilibrado la situación.  Digamos que el recibimiento ha estado en línea con los otro sitios, pero no por ello creo que este tipo de preguntas merezcan ser cerradas

Comment: @eferion yo no estoy de acuerdo con lo que argumentan ... no solo seguimos un criterio para cerrar las preguntas ... hay un sin numero de criterios que seguimos que ayudan a mantener la salud del sitio estable, aunque eso conlleve el sacrificio de visitas o view ...

Comment: Otras consultas del mismo autor: ¿por qué los autos tiene cuatro ruedas? ¿Por qué tienen que ser todas del mismo tamaño?

Comment: Yo la verdad, no entiendo porque les parece una pregunta trivial, cuando la pregunta es totalmente logica.. porque no existe un tipo de dato infinito? pensar que cualquier persona que acaba de iniciar, lo sabe, es un error.. y no, google no lo sabe.. preguntenselo...

Comment: Cuando leí el título entré directamente a responderle pero justo se cerró y me quedé con las ganas en los dedos. Después recibió votos positivos y lo abrieron, pero da cosa. Hay otras preguntas que son más simples como que la respuesta es que le falta un `;` y esas andan ahí sueltas y esta la cerraron enseguida. En fin, supongo que algún moderador estricto estaba atento ese día.

Comment: @Dreyf como usuario con reputacion para ver los autores de los votos de cierre una vez cerrada la pregunta, revisé el historial de la pregunta y te confirmo que fueron 3 personas distintas las que votaron el cierre, no un moderador. Y sobre lo otro, me parece raro que quede abierta una pregunta asi, pues uno de los motivos de cierre es "parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o que contiene errores tipograficos"

Comment: @DanteS. a este me refería: A este me refería: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/547534/no-se-por-que-mi-codigo-me-dice-que-tengo-un-error-en-printf

Comment: Y no sabía que ese tipo de preguntas se reportan con ese motivo. Yo intenté reportarlo pero no sabía a cual darle así que lo dejé nomás.

Comment: Perdon, entendi mal entonces. Estoy en celular, mañana veo como puedo ver el historial (con la otra pude por que fue editada).

Comment: Yo lo que te dije fue un motivo de cierre. No se ya que cosas se pueden reportar.

Comment: Gente que tiene en la cabeza que se debe mostrar codigo en todo, simplemente no piensan, votan de forma mecanica y punto

Comment: Discusión similiar de hace un tiempo, flexibilidad sobre cierto tipo de preguntas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4183/deber%c3%adamos-permitir-preguntas-que-buscan-respuestas-tipo-wiki

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay que perderle el temor a las respuestas de conceptos puntuales en programación. Es una pregunta valiosa que, apenas lo permitieron, recibió una gran respuesta y seguro le va a servir a un montón de gente.

PD. Sobran los comentarios a las respuestas que ridiculizan / intentan en vano reducir al absurdo. Son para meta o el chat.

Answer (score 2):

Es una excelente pregunta que tiene una excelente respuesta, ni bien la vi cerrada yo voté por reabrirla.

Ni siquiera me parece ligeramente basada en opiniones, la respuesta es totalmente objetiva.