# ¿Son indispensables tantos votos negativos?

Tags: discusión, votos, usuarios-nuevos

Normalmente siempre que veo preguntas con recompensa, tienden a tener votos positivos, sin embargo, esta pregunta fue golpeada con varios negativos, le dieron como piñata en fiesta infantil.

El escenario es simple: un usuario que quiere ocultar un elemento HTML. He visto usuarios que quieren bloquear el click derecho con tal de mantener "segura" la página y lo que desconocen es que mediante un `view-source:URL` en el chrome les permite visualizar todo.

[image]

Efecto de desconocimiento, efecto de aprendizaje, son usuarios nuevos en todo el sentido de la palabra,  **¿sería mucho pedir que tengamos paciencia y dar una buena guía?** Digo, nadie ha nacido con un tutorial de la vida, y en el ámbito de la programación, todos tienen niveles diferentes: hay quienes llevan años haciendo `hello words` en N lenguajes y quienes llevan meses con pases a producción dignos de aplausos.

Entiendo que la frustración generada por el cansancio de ver un aumento de baja calidad de preguntas, les obligue a dar negativos a diestra y siniestra, es comprensible y no digo que esté mal, hay preguntas que se lo merecen, sin embargo, esta pregunta para ser específico: [ocultar elemento del codigo fuente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329365/ocultar-elemento-del-codigo-fuente) siento que no ha merecido tantos negativos, quizás 1 o 2 a lo mucho considerando la suma de comentarios en dicha pregunta y sus potenciales respuestas donde explican a detalle.

Quizás sea una de las preguntas que pasan a la historia de SOes, en este caso, por recompensa con efecto negativo.

¡Venga vamos! Que si queremos mejorar como comunidad, tenemos que aumentar un poquito más la empatía, un poquito nada más, ¿cómo te sentirías si estuvieras en la situación de ese usuario que lanza una recompensa y te dan negativos hasta para regalar? ¿Tendrías las ganas de volver a preguntar?

Comment: también es raro que tenga +2...

Comment: Me late que fue de 2 usuarios buena onda para contrarrestar la avalancha de negativos.

Comment: ¿No sería al revés que los negativos fueron para contrarrestar los +2?

Comment: De ser ese el caso, se les pasó la mano...

Comment: Hola @fredyfx. Sigo sin entender el por qué de los votos negativos en esta pregunta y en la pregunta que señalas. Es una observación, que desde mi punto de vista es válida la que haces.

Comment: @David pues la verdad, ni idea. Lo que sí entiendo es que es muchísimo más fácil hacer un click que redactar alguna idea :)

Comment: Asi es @fredyfx.

Comment: Y me parece curioso que a pesar de no ver fallas en la formulación de esta discusión, también tiene votos negativos. ¿Para qué es Meta entonces?

Comment: @aeportugal justamente esos votos negativos sin comentarios son parte de la discusión, "están en contra" de lo mostrado, sería útil saber el por qué, ¿verdad?

Comment: Yo fui uno de esos dos usuarios que le puso positivo, en mi opinion si esta muy mal pasado eso de tener tantos negativos, si son usuarios de 150 o menos de reputacion es mas que obvio que son nuevos y a mi parecer en lugar de ayudarlos a que mejoren sus preguntas solo los desaniman a que en un futuro ya lo hagan bien y ayuden a otros. A mi me paso cuando recien entre a stackoverflow y creo que al menos por 6 meses no entre nuevamente porque me desanimo ver una pregunta mia toda mal hecha y no sabia que estaba mal hecha para empezar, con 6 puntos negativos.

Comment: Tengan un poco mas de concideracion por los nuevos, como dice @fredyfx hay que tener un poco mas de empatia y solo bastaba con 1 o 2 puntos negativos a lo mucho. A lo mejor si estuvieramos hablando de un usuario con 1000 de reputacion o algo asi pues adelante, denle metralleta porque ya deberia de saber preguntar pero no con alguien nuevo.

Comment: @ASASCED En mi opinión un miembro de la comunidad que tiene 14 preguntas y que ha ganado más de 100 puntos de reputación ya no es un "usuario nuevo" y en particular dejo considerarlo usuario nuevo si ofrece recompensa.

Comment: Es debatible quizas, auque aun asi tienes razon, puede ser que tambien haya ganado puntos al no haber sido corregido con anterioridad y tambien podria ser culpa de ese mismo usuario por no poner atencion ya que para algo esta el instructivo pero a mi parecer el hacer algunas preguntas solamente no significa que las hagas bien y el hecho de que no tengan puntos negativos no significa que sea una pregunta bien planteada. En este caso aun asi sigo pensando que al menos deberian de tener 500 de reputacion para ser considerados usuarios experimentados o al menos unas 20 preguntas hechas.

Comment: Aunque esten todas mal eso ya seria mas culpa del usuario que de la comunidad pero eso ya lo dejo a discrecion de cada quien.

Comment: Agregando otro comentario me gustaria decir que al menos los primeros 200 puntos de reputacion son exteremadamente sencillos de conseguir de igual forma asi que con un golpe de suerte podrias tener muchos puntos y aun asi no saber como preguntar.

Comment: @ASASCED he visto usuarios con 500 y 800 puntos hacer preguntas basadas en opiniones... Coincido contigo "muchos puntos y aún así no sabere cómo preguntar".

Answer (score 9):

Resumen: Mi opinión personal es que mientras más votos mejor porque más votos reflejan más participación. En el caso referido, aunque el nombre del usuario del AP es Nuevo usuario, no se trata de un usuario nuevo.

---

No creo que ayude al sitio promover la idea de que un voto  es algo negativo y menos aún referirse a ellos como golpes.

Al contrario deberíamos resaltar que 10 miembros de la comunidad han donado su tiempo para leer la pregunta e indicar que esta "parece no tener trabajo de investigación, es poco clara o es confusa"

Por otro lado, hay que tomar en cuenta que un  otorga 10 puntos mientras que un  resta dos, así que el balance en puntos de reputación no es tan malo:

```
+2*10 -2*10 = 0
```

---

En el caso de la pregunta referida el AP no es un usuario nuevo. A los usuarios nuevos se les identifica con el indicador "Nuevo colaborador".

[image]

Cabe destacar que de acuerdo al historial de la pregunta todos los votos fueron dados luego de que el AP ofreciera la recompensa.

Relacionado

- [¿Qué deberíamos hacer a las preguntas del tipo: no he intentado pero quiero respuesta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/840/65)
- [Viabilidad de puntuar negativamente a usuarios nuevos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3519/65)

Referencias

- [Come Take a Look at our New Contributor Indicator!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/289691)

Comment: Hermano, he visto un sinfín de preguntas bajo el mismo concepto, y esta es la primera pregunta que he visto de ese tipo a la que le ponen recompensa y saltan los votos negativos; no estoy en contra de los votos negativos por cierto, es una medida de mantener la calidad. Lo que me gustaría resaltar en esta publicación es la exageración de los votos negativos a una pregunta de un usuario relativamente nuevo (recién tiene como 3 meses en el sitio, ojo, he visto usuarios de más de 500 de reputación lanzar preguntas basadas en opiniones...)

Comment: @fredyfx He visto que el OP en cuestión tiene otra pregunta del mismo estilo (un par de líneas, que no parece tener trabajo de investigación) que recibido varios  ¿la has visto? Me parece que esos votos hacen mas daño al sitio que los dados a la pregunta que aquí se discute.

Comment: No hermano, esa pregunta no la he visto, y sí, comparto la idea contigo. ¿Qué podemos hacer para regular eso? Si lanzan preguntas con bajísima calidad y hay usuarios que les dan votos +,¿Tan mal está yendo la educación en hispanoamérica?

Comment: @fredyfx ¿Qué podemos hacer...? ¡Muy buena pregunta! Por lo pronto voy esperar un poco para ver como evoluciona la pregunta de la que trate este hilo, particularmente me gustaría ver a que respuesta se le otorga la recompensa y en particular los comentarios que deje el OP.

Comment: El problema aqui es que a pesar de que nosotros que ya llevamos un buen rato aqui en stackoverflow los nuevos usuarios en su mayoria son jovenes y se toman mas a pecho ese voto negativo en sus preguntas. No digo que haya que ser blandos pero al punto de hacer parecer que sus preguntas no deberian de estar ahi pues creo que eso solo los desalienta o almenos es lo que yo pienso sigo y seguire pensando que a los nuevos o personas con menos de 500 de reputacion o algo asi esten limitados a 2 votos en contra y mientras mas vayan subiendo mas votos posibles en contra.

Comment: Creo quue despues de los 500 puntos de reputacion ya deberias saber a la perfeccion como hacer buenas preguntas.

Comment: @fredyfx He actualizado mis respuesta. En cuanto a ver como evoluciona la pregunta, ninguna respuesta ganó la recompensa y en cuanto a que podemos hacer, en estos momentos se me antoja solicitar que el nombre de usuario Nuevo usuario sea baneado pero antes de eso ¿qué te hizo pensar que el AP era un usuario nuevo? ¿Su nombre de usuario?

Answer (score 5):

Voy analizar el caso usando los siguientes argumentos:

- [El privilegio de dar recompensas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) se obtiene al ganar 75 puntos por lo que se puede deducir que el usuario es activo en SOes.
- El objetivo de dar recompensas es atraer atención, y la atención puede traer consecuencias positivas o negativas. Si la pregunta es de calidad entonces muchos usuarios daran *upvotes*, y si es mala *downvotes*. Por lo que un efecto de dar recompensas es amplificar el número de votos.
- Un voto no es un golpe, es solo una manifestación de que un usuario si esta de acuerdo o desacuerdo con que la pregunta/respuesta sea válida para SO, es decir si para el usuario la pregunta es o no es de calidad.

Considerando lo anterior concluyo que cualquier usuario que desee atención extra a su pregunta debe proveer la mejor pregunta posible sino *el tiro le saldrá por la culata*, y parece que este fue el caso.

---

Ya que paso más tiempo en SOen voy a señalar mi experiencia en casos similares en esa comunidad. Para evitar que los *downvotes* afecten demasiado al usuario(muchos *downvotes* podrian quitarle el privilegio de preguntar) nos recomiendo levantar una bandera para que un moderador diamantado elimine la recompensa si es necesario por lo que probablemente la cantidad de *downvotes* no llegue a ser tan grande. Quizas se pueda hacer eso en este caso.

Answer (score 3):

El Voto Negativo es una de las herramientas más útiles como usuario no moderador dentro de todo Stack exchange,

En realidad creo que incluso habría que fomentar los *Downvotes* pues son la herramienta de la comunidad para decir esta publicación no cumple con los criterios de calidad en el sitio, ya sea que no tuvieron investigación previa, o que no incluyan suficiente información en el caso de preguntas. o bien esta solución no sirve en el caso de las respuestas.

Debemos tener en cuenta que los *downvotes* no son al usuario sino a la publicación, y que son un mecanismo con el cual le estás indicando al usuario que nos ayude a ayudarlo.